# Как считать с файла целое число, с созданием переменной для неё?

Tags: c#

Есть файл под названием input.txt, в него записано целое число, например 543.

Как считать число с файла и создать переменную с присвоением значения этого числа: int number = 543 ?

Comment: 1) Открыть файл. 2) Прочитать строку 3) Распарсить строку в число и присвоить переменной

Comment: @CrazyElf 1) Как открыть файл? 2) Как прочитать строку в ней? Какие в С# инструменты я могу использовать для этих действий?

Comment: У микрософта прекрасное руководство по `C#`, грех им не пользоваться https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-determine-whether-a-string-represents-a-numeric-value

Answer (score 0):

Нужное число будет в переменной 'result', если там есть число типа int в первой строке

```
var input = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
int.TryParse(input.First(), out int result);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin - добавил имя переменной куда результат запишется